# How to get data from API with ajax on select (dropdown option value) in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a case in my code, the result does not appear or work, the city form select is still blank. Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Province</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="province" id="province">

    <?php foreach($state_data->data as $sd){ ?>
    <option id="<?php echo $sd->code; ?>" value="<?php echo $sd->code; ?>" <?php echo (isset($this->session->userdata))?(($this->session->userdata('session_state_code') == $sd->code)?"selected":""):"";?>>
      <?php echo $sd->name ;?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="city_section">
  <label>City</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">

    <?php foreach($city_data->data as $cd){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cd->code; ?>" <?php echo (isset($this->session->userdata))?(($this->session->userdata('session_city_code') == $cd->code)?"selected":""):"";?>>
      <?php echo $cd->name ;?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

This the javascript to get data from the controller:

```js
$('#province').on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>edit_profile/get_city",
        data: {
          id: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('select#city').html('');
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("<option />").val(data[i].code)
              .text(data[i].name)
              .appendTo($('select#city'));
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

and this the controller to get data from API:

```php
public function get_city(){
  $m_url = URL_API;
  $function = "get_location";
  $i = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $url = $m_url . "/" . $function . "?" . "t=city" . "&" . "i=".$i;
  $json_data = file_get_contents($url);
  $data = json_decode($json_data);  
}
```

Comment: any error u get in console ?

Comment: no, i dont get @ManinderpreetSingh

Answer (score 1):

Your function does't return anything to ajax you need to `echo`  json_decode

```
public function get_city(){
        $m_url = URL_API;
        $function = "get_location";
        $i = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $url = $m_url . "/" . $function . "?" . "t=city" . "&" . "i=".$i;
        $json_data = file_get_contents($url);
        echo $data = json_decode($json_data);// use echo here
    }
```

Comment: I add echo but still same @Saty

Answer (score 0):

You dont need json_decode(), just print $json_data. Because, it's already returns as string by file_get_contents().

```
public function get_city(){

    $m_url = URL_API;
    $function = "get_location";
    $i = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $url = $m_url . "/" . $function . "?" . "t=city" . "&" . "i=".$i;
    $json_data = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $json_data;


}
```

Convert returned data to JSON object. And then use it:

```
   success: function(data) {
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
      $('select#city').html('');
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
        $("<option />").val(jsonObj[i].code)
          .text(jsonObj[i].name)
          .appendTo($('select#city'));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have add your advice but dont effect anything. but thanks. what about my ajax?

Comment: Convert the returned string to JSON object. You are missed it.

Comment: I have converted but still empty

Answer (score 0):

Having `echo $json_data;` ,now try to put `error` callback in your Ajax so that you will see the error response of your request. From there you will have an idea what went wrong within the process.

```
error: function(err){
  console.log(err.responseText);
}
```

Comment: there is no error result/ response friend. thanks for your advice

Comment: Instead of `data: {
          id: $(this).val()
        },` should be `data: {
          'id': id
        },` since you have `var id= $(this).val()` .